# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax. Error in my Update SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Can you please tell me what may be wrong in my SQL query?

SQL query:

```
UPDATE  'wp7b_5_usermeta' SET  'meta_key' = REPLACE(  'meta_key',  'wp_',  'wp7b_5_' ) WHERE  'meta_key' LIKE  'wp_%'
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''wp7b_5_usermeta' SET 'meta_key' = REPLACE ('meta_key', 'wp_', 'wp7b_5_') WHERE ' at line 1

Comment: It seems you should remove quotes around the table name, or replace with ` .... `( back ticks )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to remove single quote for column and table name

```
 UPDATE  wp7b_5_usermeta
 SET  meta_key = REPLACE( meta_key,  'wp_',  'wp7b_5_' )
 WHERE  meta_key LIKE  'wp_%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If table name is not reserved from MySql , using single quote give this error message so change it like:

Can you please tell me what may be wrong in my SQL query?

SQL query:

```
UPDATE wp7b_5_usermeta SET meta_key = REPLACE( 'meta_key', 'wp_', 'wp7b_5_' ) WHERE 'meta_key' LIKE 'wp_%'
```

> NOTE:
>
> If your table name is reserved from Mysql  you need to use single quote.